# ROS wrapper for very simple cases

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish to learn about wrapping software for porting into ROS. As a start, can someone help me with this basic C++ program which gives output as 'Hello World !', can it be made into a ROS package and then using ROS commands to make this program work ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Any help is most appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12298/ros-wrapper-for-very-simple-cases/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-12-11**:
You are aware of the beginner tutorials for ROS, right? Most of this shows up in much more detail here: http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials, specifically in 'http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have no ROS dependencies (message packages, etc) then it's basically just like using CMake. You simply need to create a package (using roscreate-pkg), and then add your executable to the list of things to build in the CMakeFiles.txt. After building, rosrun/roslaunch will automatically find the executables inside your package.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-09**:
@fergs  : .... thank you, and how does things change with ROS dependencies (say something like rviz) ?

**Comment by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on 2013-03-06**:
If dependencies are added, you will need to specify them in CMakeFiles.txt . It is convenient to specify from start:
example
roscreate-pkg example_package dependent_package

Consult this link:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage